# vdots in between of two columns

Tags: matrices

I am trying to make a matrix like the following:

[image]

but I am not sure how it is possible. since `\vdots` add 3 dots for each column, I try to do a hack like this:

```
 \begin{equation}  \label{eq:lsq3}
\begin{bmatrix} x_1& &1\\&.&\\&.&\\&.&\\x_n& &1\end{bmatrix}    \nonumber 
\end{equation}
```

but it is not working. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a matrix with only one column, where the first and last entry is separated by a space:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x_1& &1\\&.&\\&.&\\&.&\\x_n& &1
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x_1\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n\ 1
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a TABstack, you decide the horizontal gap between columns.  In the first example, it is 0pt, in the second, it is 0.5ex.  The only quirk is that I had to lower the `\vdots` a little to achieve vertical symmetry.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[ \mathbf{X} = \bracketMatrixstack{
x_1&                               &1\\
   &\protect\raisebox{-2pt}{\vdots}& \\
x_n&                               & 1
} \]
\setstacktabbedgap{.5ex}
\[ \mathbf{X} = \bracketMatrixstack{
x_1&                               &1\\
   &\protect\raisebox{-2pt}{\vdots}& \\
x_n&                               & 1
} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can dispense with the `\protect`s if one loads package `fixltx2e`.